# xpath selenium multi/and operators

Tags: selenium, xpath

Could anybody help how to solve this dilemma

```
I have this code:
  <div>
    <a href="/cars/102392-2">Link</a>
    <span class="make">Chevrolet</span><br>
    <span class="year">1956</span><br>
    <span class="price">$20,000</span><br>
  </div>

  <div>
    <a href="/cars/152933-11">Link</a>
    <span class="make">Ford</span><br>
    <span class="year">1958</span><br>
    <span class="price">$21,000</span><br>
  </div>
```

I need get the link for example Fords with the year greater then 1950.

Presently, I am using following xpath:

```
//*[text()='Ford' and .//text()>'1950']//parent::a
```

And this doesn't work! Have you any idea ?

Comment: text()>'1950' won't work because text() deals with Strings only

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is one possible XPath :

```
//div[span/text()='Ford' and span/text()>1950]/a
```

Basically the XPath check if `div` has child `span` with text equals 'Ford' and another child `span` with value greater than 1950. Then from such `div` that match the two criteria above, return child `a` element.

**<kbd>[`demo`](http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath/187e8222b38f335b554ba7a258e4b0a7)</kbd>**

Better yet, only check `span` with class 'make' for manufacturer and `span` with class 'year' for manufacturing year :

```
//div[span[@class='make']='Ford' and span[@class='year']>1950]/a
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write a generic method to get the required links, as shown below:

```
public static List<WebElement> getLinks(String linkText, int year) {
    List<WebElement> links = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//a[text()='" + linkText + "']/following-sibling::span[1]"));
        List<WebElement> linksGreaterThanRequiredYear = new ArrayList<WebElement>();
        for (WebElement link : links) {
            if (Integer.parseInt(link.getText()) > year)
                linksGreaterThanRequiredYear.add(link);
        }
        return linksGreaterThanRequiredYear;
}
```

Hence, if you want to get the Fords with year greater than 1950, you can call above method in following way:

```
 List<WebElement> fordsWithYearGreaterThan1950 = getLinks("Ford", 1950);
```

Above method can be further enhanced to include less than criteria as well. Let me know, if you have any further queries.

Comment: Thank you so much, I found too the solution in xpath syntax !